# How do humans meet the brain’s glucose demand of 420kcal (105g sugar) per day on a healthy diet?

Tags: brain, nutrition, diet, glucose, sugar

How do humans meet the brain’s glucose demand of 420kcal (105g sugar) per day on a healthy diet? Wouldn't the protein demand in case of gluconeogenesis be tremendous?

https://web.archive.org/web/20170315181331/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22436/

Comment: @NeoGenAalem, gluconeogenesis is not only from proteins but also from lactate and fats as stated in the article you linked to: "The main precursors for gluconeogenesis are lactate and alanine from muscle, glycerol from adipose tissue, and glucogenic amino acids from the diet.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your diet is carbohydrates, which are or can be directly converted into sugars, Vegetables, fruits, and grains are all primarily carbohydrates. Unless you are eating a exclusively animal based diet getting glucose for the brain is not difficult.

Contrary to what fad diets claim a [healthy diet contains a lot of carbohydrates](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/carbohydrates/art-20045705). What is unhealthy is when your diet contains only refined pure carbohydrates and not the vitamins fiber and other nutrients.